# Copying Table of Contents from QGIS into Excel?

Tags: qgis-plugins, excel, table-of-contents

Is there a way to copy and paste the contents of the Table of Contents in QGIS into an Excel spreadsheet?

For example, I have many layers (groups of vector shapefiles which are underneath various 'groups' which I would like to maintain/keep these categories when transferring the file names across to the sheet) which I would like to preserve when copying and pasting.

It is not the attribute table itself, and I can't just copy and paste the legend of a print out map as I need to be able to have this as text.

Comment: No, not a simple copy and paste but you can iterate the layers in the canvas in PyQGIS and expand the group layers writing to a text file. Do you have any python ability?